# Maping one spectral data to another with CNN

Tags: neural-networks

We have a data from Vis spectrometer that is normalized but needs correction. We also have data from calibrated colorimeter. Idea is to learn a neural network that will correct spectra from the vis spectrometer so they would resemble spectra from the colorimeter. I trained convolutional auto-encoder to do this but results are barely satisfying. Are there any known architectures and papers on this matter? I wasn't able to find any.

Architecture of my auto-encoder looks like that:

```
    c1 = Conv1D(16, 11, strides=1, padding='same')(input)
    a1 = Activation('relu')(c1)
    m1 = MaxPool1D(pool_size=2, padding='same')(a1)
    
    c2 = Conv1D(32, 9, padding='same')(m1)
    a2 = Activation('relu')(c2)
    m2 = MaxPool1D(pool_size=2, padding='same')(a2)
    
    c3 = Conv1D(64, 7, padding='same')(m2)
    a3 = Activation('relu')(c3)
    m3 = MaxPool1D(pool_size=2, padding='same')(a3)
    
    c4 = Conv1D(128, 5, padding='same')(m3)
    a4 = Activation('relu')(c4)

    u1 = UpSampling1D(2)(a4)
    
    uc2 = Conv1D(64, 7, padding='same')(u1)
    a7 = Activation('relu')(uc2)
    u2 = UpSampling1D(2)(a7)
    
    uc3 = Conv1D(32, 9, strides=1, padding='same')(u2)
    a8 = Activation('relu')(uc3)
    u3 = UpSampling1D(2)(a8)
    
    uc4 = Conv1D(16, 11, strides=1, padding='same')(u3)
    a9 = Activation('relu')(uc4)
    u4 = UpSampling1D(2)(a9)
    flat = Flatten()(a9)
    dens = Dense(input_size, activation='sigmoid')(flat)

    return Model(inputs=[input], outputs=[dens])
```

Edit:
I have over 660 spectra of colores measured by colorimeter on calibration plate. I also have vis-spectrometer that measured the same calibration plate. Data from spectrometer is normalized. Neural network is trained on 660 spectra, where each training set consists of 224 bands of data from spectrometer as training data and 224 bands of data from colorimeter as ground truth. That gives 147840 data points of both training and ground truth data. Presented model work to some degree in correcting spectrometer data.

[image: Specim - spectrometer, Exact - colorimeter]

This is representation of the calibration plate with spectra from colorimeter and from predictions from trained model

[image]

Comment: Is there any particular reason why the model has to be an autoencoder or even a neural network? Do you have a sense of what kind of a relationship might exist between the spectrometer and the colorimeter? For instance, is there a monotonic relationship? Neural networks are challenging to estimate and can discover spurious associations and trends, so I'm asking if there's a way to be more specific about the form of the model.

Comment: There is no particular reason for it to be an autoencoder or even neural network. It was just an idea that I thought may help. I tried using simple linear model to estimate correction parameters that I could apply to the data from spectrometer, it didn't work that well. That's why I moved to NN, the releationship is non trivial because of the way XYZ tristimulus values work.

Comment: With the addition of the plot and this clarifying comment, this seems like a job for spline regression.

Comment: Whould spline regression work if I have 660 spectra that could be very distinct from one another. Plot is just example of one possible spectrum and I want my NN to be more generalized.

Comment: My interpretation of the plot was that you wanted to use the values on the horizontal to predict the values on the vertical, and that this plot is the only item of concern for your problem. If you have a different concerns, such as what to do with hundreds of such plots, then you should edit your post to clarify.

Comment: Ok, I edited the post.

Comment: FWIW, the [tag:spectral-analysis] tag is something quite different from the physical spectra examined in your question, so I've removed it.